# Parsing strings from CSS code

Tags: c#, css, parsing

A RSS feed that I need to parse works in the way of putting all the information into the description element in CSS to make a nice table in a viewer, this makes it hard to parse the actual strings from it. E.g. below is one of the description elements:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color:#493800; font-size: 11px; border:solid 1px #bababa;    margin: 10px;"><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Start Time</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">21/11/2013 19:30 UTC</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Backup Job</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">Backup</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Computer</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">theComputer</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Disk</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">theDisk</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Username</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">theUsername</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Searched</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">112306 (52.5 GB)</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Uploaded</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">121 (29.1 MB)</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Duration</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">0:19:23</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Errors</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">0</td></tr><tr><th style="padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;">Result</th><td style="padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;">COMPLETE</td></tr></table> <p><a href="LINK">Details</a></p
```

Inside all the CSS is various things like Computer: Computername, Uploaded: Amountuploaded and I need to get this stuff but have no idea how too, I have tried using HTML agility pack but could not get it to work, but I am pretty bad with it.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's not in any CSS.. its just part of the markup..

Comment: Oh.. I thought it was CSS? Is there any way to parse this then? What do I even search to get information on parsing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169598/Parse-XML-Documents-by-XMLDocument-and-XDocument gives some info on parsing XML content in C#. Yeah, it looks to me like you can just use .NET's Xml objects to parse it.

You need to read about .NET's Xml Document parsing. This article is a good start.

To get the string into an XmlDocument, you just use:

```
string xTxt = "<table style=\"border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color:#493800; font-size: 11px; border:solid 1px #bababa;    margin: 10px;\"><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Start Time</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">21/11/2013 19:30 UTC</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Backup Job</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">Backup</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Computer</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">theComputer</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Disk</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">theDisk</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Username</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">theUsername</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Searched</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">112306 (52.5 GB)</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Uploaded</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">121 (29.1 MB)</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Duration</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">0:19:23</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Errors</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">0</td></tr><tr><th style=\"padding:5px; background:#ddd; border:solid 1px #bababa; color:#493800; font-size: 10px;\">Result</th><td style=\"padding:5px; margin:0; background:#fff;\">COMPLETE</td></tr></table><p><a href=\"LINK\">Details</a></p>";
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root>" + xTxt + "</root>");

string t = null;
XmlNodeList trNodes = d.SelectNodes("//tr");
foreach (XmlNode n in trNodes)
{
    XmlNode thNode = n.SelectSingleNode("th");
    XmlNode tdNode = n.SelectSingleNode("td");
    t += thNode.InnerText + ':';
    t += tdNode.InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
}
txtInfo.AppendText("nodes.Count = " + nodes.Count + '\n');
txtInfo.AppendText(t);
```

notice that each item that you want is in a TR HTML element with the name of the item in a TH elemement and the value in a TD element. that helps you find them easily. so we grab all 10 'tr' elements in trNodes with the above code.

in the above example, i have a `TextBox` named txtInfo that i use to see my results. but i encourage you to not even store the results in a string variable. my use of the `t` string variable is simply so you can see one way to convert the items to another form. of course, those thNode.InnerText and tdNode.InnerText methods are what grabs each item.

you may want to create a List items, or maybe better you might want to create a class that specifically has each property, but i don't know if each property will change. but you could create a class which does all this processing and use that class in your project. whatever you want. :)

happy coding!

Comment: I've read through a lot of that stuff and have had no luck at all, I can do it if I can find something that gets rid of all the "markup" stuff but without that I have no idea.

Comment: that's why you need to learn about how to use the .NET Xml objects. i'll see what i can figure out in the next half hour for you. ;)

Comment: Oh ok, I thought the RSS feed was already an XML document, you want to make a new one with the string? and then want to use the XML parses on this new XML, do I have to store this temporary XML somewhere or can it all be handled in VS?

Comment: Ok I see the TR thing now makes sense, how do we get rid of everything else in the trs?

Comment: you gave us no code, so i just ran with the string you gave in your question. if it's already in an XmlDocument, then you can use that or you can grab the text and create a new XmlDocument, however you want. but the solution i've started to show in the above code is to use XPath to select a list of nodes that you want. then you can loop thru each node and grab the name and value that you want. and you can put it in any form you want.

Comment: i'll work on further parsing the TR nodes now. :) i encourage you to read about XPath. w3schools is one descent resource for quick intro to such things.

Comment: Thanks XPath seems like something really cool to know, I have added it to my reading list. Sorry for being such a noob, I am pretty new to this sort of stuff, this is the first time I have incorporated outside data into my programs.

Comment: thanks. and no problem. we all start at the beginning. :) if you enjoy it, just keep learning it. if you don't, find something you enjoy. :) So i found the solution, i will edit my above post now with the C# code.

Comment: i really don't know XPath well. but that's because i don't use it a lot. i know where to find the info when i need it. so if i need some XPath, i just look it up real quick. but of course i did read a bit about XPath to get the general understanding, and try not to forget too much. but it's no problem forgetting the details since real life is *usually* an open-book test.. or an open-internet test, as you are here asking for a solution on the net too. :) w3schools is a good resource tho. of course, stackoverflow is too. :) connectionstrings.com is another. :) Plz vote my answer as useful. ;)